# SASS - sourcemap location

Tags: css, sass

I was wondering when compiling a SASS file (scss) if you can designate where it creates the .css.map file just having trouble finding the parameters documentation.

I'm assuming it would be something along the lines of "--sourcemap="XXX"

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no additional options for `--sourcemap` nor for the `sourcemap = true` in your config.rb

However, you can move the map and manually edit the sourceMappingURL comment at the bottom of the generated CSS file after processing: `/*# sourceMappingURL=directory/app.css.map */`

Comment: Yeah I had been doing that but I was hoping to be able to have a preset so it isn't sitting in the same directory as the compiled css file.